# Populating text input in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to do the following (amongst many other attempts), and have validated that #myVar# holds data and is current in the scope, but nothing works. Any ideas how to populate a text input in Coldfusion? Many thanks in advance!

```
<cfoutput>#myVar#</cfoutput>
<script>document.getElementById("text1").value = #myVar# </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your value a string or an integer? If its a string you will need wrap the value in quotes.

Additionally you will want to use the `jsStringFormat()` function to ensure any quotes are escaped.

```
<script>document.getElementById("text1").value = "#jsStringFormat(myVar)#"; </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is with the value attribute of an input tag.

```
<form>
<input name "fred" value="flinstone">
etc
```

If you want to populate it dynamically, use cfoutput.

```
<cfset myVar = "flinstone">
<cfoutput>
<form>
<input name "fred" value="#myVar#">
etc
```

or is that not the question?

Comment: Many thanks. That will work for my current purposes, but what if I want to change a an input value programatically using a JavaScript (client-side) function, prior to submitting the form? How can I change a <cfinput type="text" id="myInput1" name="myInput1"> using JavaScript? Tks!

Comment: That would be a separate question.  When you come to that situation, start with straight html and static values.  Then you'll have the javascript part down.  Then look at the various ways of passing coldfusion variables to javascript.  Keep each step simple.

Answer (score 2):

Your closing `</cfoutput>` is too early, where you're trying to output the value inside your javascript should also be wrapped in the cfoutput.

```
<cfoutput>
    #myVar#
    <script>document.getElementById("text1").value = "#myVar#";</script>
</cfoutput>
```